# Will a "debt trap" be an effective measure to increase the geopolitical influence of a nation?

Tags: international, geopolitics, belt-and-road-initiative

According to this article published in [Economic Times](https://m.economictimes.com/news/defence/chinas-new-super-weapon-against-india-neighbourhood-debt-traps/amp_articleshow/63296724.cms), China is trying to deploy "debt trap" as a measure to increase its geopolitical influence over nations surrounding India using the Belt and Road Initiative.

So how can debt traps for let's say Pakistan, help China to increase its influence over Pakistan or other nations?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the book "Diaries of an Economic Hitman", a great book that essentially revolves around this topic

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you offer loans that are not realistically serviceable (the terms of the loan exceed realistic expected cash flow of the project being financed - see as example ["The World's Emptiest Airport" in Sri Lanka](https://qz.com/896219/chinese-investment-aid-to-sri-lanka-has-been-a-major-success-for-china/))

Then, the country is faced with necessity of either defaulting on the loan, or, doing what the lender (China) wants, such as offering ports etc...

Detailed explanations and examples can be found:

- https://qz.com/896219/chinese-investment-aid-to-sri-lanka-has-been-a-major-success-for-china/
- https://qz.com/1223768/china-debt-trap-these-eight-countries-are-in-danger-of-debt-overloads-from-chinas-belt-and-road-plans/
- http://www.atimes.com/article/sri-lanka-latest-victim-chinas-debt-trap-diplomacy/